# SQL query to find items which are recently updated and not deleted

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with the structure :

| Code | Time | Delete indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2023-07-26 17:00:00 | 1 |
| A1 | 2023-07-25 15:00:00 | 0 |
| A2 | 2023-07-26 11:00:00 | 0 |
| A2 | 2023-07-25 18:00:00 | 1 |
| A3 | 2023-07-22 10:00:00 | 1 |
| A3 | 2023-07-26 9:00:00 | 0 |

I want a query which gives me all codes which have the most recent updated record with delete indicator as 1. The time can between a provided specific range like 25 july to 30 july.

Expected output :

| Code | Time | Delete indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2023-07-26 17:00:00 | 1 |

Output has A1 with time 2023-07-26 17:00:00 because it has delete indicator as 1. Older record should not be taken into consideration
A2 is not there because its most recent record of 2023-07-26 11:00:00 has delete indicator as 0
A3 is not there because its most recent record of 2023-07-26 9:00:00 has delete indicator as 0 and older record of 22 july is anyway out of range

Tried Group by Code but it didnt work because I want all columns in output

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select t1.*
from my_table t1
    left join my_table t2 on t1.Time > t2.Time
where t2.Code is null and t1.deleted = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Products Table]

Try this (for two entry comparison):

```
SELECT p1.* FROM products p1
left join products p2 on p2.code = p1.code
where p1.time > p2.time
and p1.is_deleted = 1;
```

Try this (for multiple entry comparison):

```
select * from products where (code, time) in 
(select code, max(time) from products group by code)
and is_deleted = 1;
```

Comment: select t.code , t.time, t.is_deleted from products t,
(select code, max(time) time from products group by code)  p where t.code = p.code
and t.time = p.time and t.is_deleted=1;